# APK to web based App

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, apk

I have tried to accomplish this by using chromeos-apk found on github, but that is just not a solution for me.

Also is there a way to run java on the server so i don't have to require people to download java?

Comment: What would be the best way of taking an APK and converting it for the web. I have access to all the core JAVA files. Should i rewrite the app using html, javascript etc. or is there a way i could take the java i have and run it on the server?

Comment: It is relatively simple to take a web-page and package it as an APK (using something like Cordova), but alas, moving the opposite direction is not as straight forward. If you must use Java, look into JSP or similar technologies. Go read some basic tutorials on web programming to become familiar with it and then come back here if you still don't have any idea where to go.

Comment: @chrisFranklin if i use JSP would the user be required to download and run java on their computer? I only ask because Chromebooks don't allow Java.

Comment: JSP stands for JavaServer Page, and is a server side rendering option for web pages. The user receives zero Java code in their page. Instead, all processing is done on the server before the page is sent to the browser to be rendered as pure HTML/Javascript/CSS. There are a lot of other technologies that do the same thing with Java on the server side. Just do a little digging and you will find them.

Comment: @ChrisFranklin thank you very much, i was pretty sure it was all done server side, i just dont know much about Java is all.  Thanks!